# ASP.NET Area Server Error

Tags: c#, .net

I have area everything work fine but when I try to connect Admin Area like this

```
http://localhost:3000/Admin
```

I get an error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Here is my AdminAreaRegistration

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName => "Admin";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); in the register routes method and test it

Comment: I get an error A route named 'Admin_default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name